# Get list of organizations on GitHub

Tags: github, github-api, github-organizations

Is there a workaround to get the list of organizations on GitHub?

For example: https://github.com/showcases/open-source-organizations

How can we do that via the GitHub API or GitHub search?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get a list of all accounts:

https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-all-users

The `type` parameter will tell you if it's a user or organization.

An alternative is to use the search API:

https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users

You can specify `type:org` to get organizations only:

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=type:org

Comment: how can i get objective C project of all organizations?

Comment: @ZuzooVn I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: I want to get the list of organizations which have project with Objective C language.

Comment: That's not possible currently. A workaround you could use is to get a list of all projects marked as Objective-C (using the Search API), and then get the owner of each project. If the owner is an organization (and not a personal account), you'd keep it in the list of organizations.

Answer (score 8):

[On June 17, 2015](https://developer.github.com/changes/2015-06-17-organizations-endpoint/) GitHub added a new API to get organizations:

```
curl https://api.github.com/organizations

[
  {
    "login": "github",
    "id": 9919,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github",
   "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github/repos",
   "events_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github/events",
   "members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github/members{/member}",
   "public_members_url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github/public_members{/member}",
   "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9919?v=3",
    "description": "GitHub, the company."
  },
  ...
]
```

Additional information can be found on [the following link](https://developer.github.com/v3/orgs/#list-all-organizations):

### List all organizations

Lists all organizations, in the order that they were created on GitHub.

Note: Pagination is powered exclusively by the `since` parameter. Use the [Link header](https://developer.github.com/v3/#link-header) to get the URL for the next page of organizations.

**Parameters**

- **Name**: since
- **Type**: string
- **Description**: The integer ID of the last Organization that you've seen.

**Response**

```
Status: 200 OK
Link: <https://api.github.com/organizations?since=135>; rel="next"
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[
  {
    "login": "github",
    "id": 1,
    "url": "https://api.github.com/orgs/github",
    "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
    "description": "A great organization"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that it's also possible to use [Github GraphQL v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/) to request organization using :

```graphql
{
  search(query: "type:org", type: USER, first: 100) {
    userCount
    nodes {
      ... on Organization {
        name
        createdAt
        description
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search%28query%3A%20%22type%3Aorg%22%2C%20type%3A%20USER%2C%20first%3A%20100%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20userCount%0A%20%20%20%20nodes%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Organization%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20createdAt%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20description%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

Answer (score 1):

With the [GitHub CLI `gh` 2.28.0 (Apr. 2023)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.28.0), you can also use the new [`gh org list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_org_list) command:

```bash
# List the first 30 organizations
$ gh org list

# List more organizations
$ gh org list --limit 100
```

Comment: This is helpful, but as of the time of this comment, this only lists organizations that you're a member of.

Comment: @BillRobertson42 True, reading [`pkg/cmd/org/list/http.go`](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/7257/files#diff-5d859b0dd3ceeca1f0703ad275b72c714664615a588de842ab137337ef03ee70R73-R75), this is based on User.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar problems with you and maybe I get an answer from github API doc now.

Detail Doc in this: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-users

There are several parameters that can be used.

1. `q` : (string). The search terms.
2. `sort` : (string). The sort field. Can be `followers`, `repositories`, or `joined`. Default: results are sorted by best match.
3. `order` : (string). The sort order if sort parameter is provided. One of `asc` or `desc`. Default: `desc`

The `q` search term can also contain any combination of the supported user search qualifiers as described by the in-browser user search documentation and search syntax documentation:

- `type` With this qualifier you can restrict the search to just personal accounts (`user`) or just organization accounts (`org`).
- `in` Qualifies which fields are searched. With this qualifier you can restrict the search to just the username (`login`), public email (`email`), full name (`fullname`), or any combination of these.
- `repos` Filters users based on the number of repositories they have.
- `location` Filter users by the location indicated in their profile.
- `language` Search for users that have repositories that match a certain language.
- `created` Filter users based on when they joined.
- `followers` Filter users based on the number of followers they have.

For your problem, you can try this example and change it.

For example:

https://api.github.com/search/users?q=language:objective-c+type:org&page=1

Request GET and return format data (json). Page parameter can be changed to get more pages of results (but no more than 1000, according current API doc).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this https://medium.com/@harshitsinghai77/demystifying-github-api-to-fetch-the-top-3-repositories-by-stars-using-node-js-aef8818551cb to have a clear understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use this request https://api.github.com/graphql :

```
query {
  enterprise(slug: "ENTERPRISE_SLUG") {
    organizations(first: 100) {
      nodes {
        name
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```